# NSMutableArray gives null when using addObject

Tags: objective-c, initialization, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to add values to the yArray. However in the NSLog, it always shows up null. I am synthesizing the NSMutableArray (yArray) and get no errors or warnings on compiling. I believe one reason might be that i am not initializing the array. I read somewhere that @synthesize does not initialize. However, i'm a beginner and i'm not sure how to properly initialize the array. I've researched it on google but couldn't figure it out. Can someone tell me how or at least point me in the right direction. I posted a part of my code below. Thank you in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    xx = xx + [[self.yArr1 objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if(i==0)
        [self.yArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(0.0)]];
    else
    {
        bb = fabs([[self.yArr1 objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]- [[self.yArr1 objectAtIndex:(i-1)] doubleValue]);
        [self.yArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(bb)]]; // This is the problem.
        yy = yy + [[self.yArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
    }
    NSLog(@"prediction %f, %f, %@, %f", bb, yy, [self.yArray objectAtIndex:i],[[self.yArr1 objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]);
}
NSLog(@"prediction %f, %f", bb, yy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly initialize the array use

```
NSMutableArray* yArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Initialize it before using it (maybe in `init` method or something like that), then retry. Don't forget to manually release it when you have done.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel pretty stupid, it seems i needed someone to point out that the statement 
self.yArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
means initializing the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize it first in a location that will be hit prior to your `addObject` code. e.g.

```
yArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thank you very much also for your reply. This really has saved me a lot of time. Since, i was just clueless on the term initializing. Didn't know doing that meant initializing.